# Grouping and Total Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called Phone_Details and the data looks like:

```
Name            DeviceType  InvoiceDate TotalCharges
Aguilera, Alex  Smart Phone 8/3/2012    606.55
Aguilera, Alex  Data Card   8/3/2012    26.17
```

I want Output as:

```
Name            Total Spend    # of devices    Avg Spend    # of Bills >300
Aguilera, Alex  632.72              2            316.36            1
```

I tried doing this:

```
Select Name,Sum(Totalcharges), Count(DeviceType),Sum(Totalcharges)/Count(DeviceType)
from dbo.Phone_Details
group by Name
```

But How can i get the last column this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Select Name,
         Sum(Totalcharges) [Total Spend],
         Count(DeviceType) [# of devices],
         Sum(Totalcharges)/Count(DeviceType) [Avg Spend],
         Count(CASE WHEN TotalCharges > 300 then 1 end)  [# of Bills > 300]
    from dbo.Phone_Details
group by Name
```

Comment: Should be `SUM(CASE)` rather than `COUNT(CASE)`, since `COUNT(0)` still registers 1.

Comment: @Michael Still "debugging" as you commented. :) It's fixed. When I'm counting, I usually use the `COUNT` version with implied ELSE NULL.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi Thank you so much!! Not sure why i missed this logic :)